# how to active my wifi?

Tags: wireless, drivers

I have bought an pci-wifi receiver.It can be used on win7.How to make it active on my linux?

```
iwlist scan
eth0 Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo Interface doesn't support scanning.

lspci -knn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller [8086:0c00] (rev 06)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8534]
Kernel driver in use: hsw_uncore
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller [8086:0c01] (rev 06)
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0402] (rev 06)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8534]
Kernel driver in use: i915
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI [8086:8c31] (rev 05)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8534]
Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:8c3a] (rev 04)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8534]
Kernel driver in use: mei_me
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 [8086:8c2d] (rev 05)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8534]
Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller [8086:8c20] (rev 05)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8576]
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 [8086:8c10] (rev d5)
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 [8086:8c14] (rev d5)
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 [8086:8c26] (rev 05)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8534]
Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation C220 Series Chipset Family H81 Express LPC Controller [8086:8c5c] (rev 05)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8534]
Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] [8086:8c02] (rev 05)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8534]
Kernel driver in use: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:8c22] (rev 05)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8534]
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 [8086:4232]
Subsystem: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 AGN [8086:1321]
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8554]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
lshw -C network
bash: lshw: command not found
iwconfig
eth0 no wireless extensions.

lo no wireless extensions.

ifconfig -a
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr e0:3f:49:57:4b:d1
inet addr:192.168.1.100 Bcast:192.168.1.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
RX packets:92 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:92 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
RX bytes:8564 (8.3 KiB) TX bytes:8564 (8.3 KiB)

No wlan0 can be seen.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 [8086:4232] uses the driver `iwlwifi`. Load it and see if the wireless comes to life:

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

Check:

```
iwconfig
```

If an interface wlan0 appears,let's get the module to load automatically on boot:

```
sudo -i
echo iwlwifi  >>  /etc/modules
exit
```

If not, check the log for clues as to why not:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
```

Post the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

I will then edit this answer to propose a fuller solution.

Comment: modprobe iwlwifi

Answer (score 0):

solved by `apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi`,now wifi can be scanned.